# Determine the primitive of the function....

Tags: integration

I have here an example , in which the primitive of the following function is required to be determined: $f(x)=|x-1| \cdot (2x-1)$.

My question is : can I split this function into two and find the primitive for each case, because I don't know whether working directly with absolute value function is efficient?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should split into two cases. In this case, where only one point has to be taken into account, it's rather easy: by the fundamental theorem of calculus, an antiderivative of $f$ is
$$
F(x)=\int_{1}^{x}f(t)\,dt=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\int_{1}^x (t-1)(2t-1)\,dt & \text{if $x\ge0$}\\[2ex]
\displaystyle\int_{1}^x (1-t)(2t-1)\,dt & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Of course you can use what you find in the upper branch for computing the lower branch; add *the same* arbitrary constant to the branches, if you need to find all antiderivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
First case
$$f(x)=|x-1| \cdot (2x-1)=(x-1)(2x-1),x\geq1$$
Second case
$$f(x)=|x-1| \cdot (2x-1)=-(x-1)(2x-1),x<1$$

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly supposed, you need to consider both cases.

The problem would have been obvious for a definite integral where the split is evidently required if $1$ belongs to the integration interval.